# Swift SpriteKit allow user to choose between player nodes

Tags: swift, user-controls

In my game, the user controls a ship which they move around.

How should I allow the user to select from a range of nodes?

For example, offering a red/blue/green ship which they can choose from or even unlock when their score = X.

Here is my code for the current player node:

```
    let shipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ship1.png")

    ship = SKSpriteNode(texture: shipTexture)
    ship.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: -self.frame.height / 3)
    ship.zPosition = 3
    ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 30, height: 100))
    ship.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    ship.run(makeShipAnimate)
    ship.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue
    ship.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue
    ship.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.ship.rawValue
    ship.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    self.addChild(ship)
```

Is there a way to allow the user to pick between "ship1.png" or "ship2.png" for example?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Something like this should get you started:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var shipName = ""//create a var to hold the chosen ship
```

Then create some buttons or a way for the user to choose which ship and create a function to handle the selection by passing in an `Int` which corresponds to a particular color:

```
func chooseShip(ship: Int) {
        switch ship {
        case 0:
            shipName = "blueShip.png"
            break
        case 1:
            shipName = "greenShip.png"
            break
        default:
            shipName = "greenShip.png"
        }
    }
```

So if the blue ship is chosen for example, that button would call the above function and pass in the selection:

```
chooseShip(ship: 0)
```

After the user has chosen you can load the image you want:

```
let shipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: shipName)
etc...
```